# UmiJs Unit test error - _umi.connect) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd, redux-saga, umijs

I am new in unit testing in reactjs.
I tried to test my login component rendering
For testing, i am using JEST and enzyme.

[This is the error, i am getting]

[image]

Test case code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Login from './index'; // Introduce the corresponding React component

it('renders Login page', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login.WrappedComponent login={{ name: '' }} />);
})
```

> i am using Real project with umi - `https://ant.design/docs/react/practical-projects`

can any one help me on this.

Comment: I really wanted to build a project with ant design as well... but me being english & the lib being mainly documented in Chinese proved too difficult. What I can recommend for you is to search for `enzyme and redux connect`. As ant design / UMI uses redux internally... So you might have more luck trying to solve for that.

Comment: This thread seems like there might be some solutions. 
https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1002. Mainly... "In your test, just extract the "pure" Component rather than the connected one"

Comment: Thanks @RohanBüchner its working

Comment: Well done! Asked & Answered your own question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use connect from react-redux instead of umi.
actually umi is also using react-redux inside of it.

Replace this line in your component :

`import { connect } from 'umi'`
with
`import { connect } from 'react-redux'`